# Scrapy get type/info about immediate next sibling

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am extracting information from a site with html that looks like:

```
<h2> <span class="mw-headline" id="Cast">Cast</span></h2>
<ul><li> <a href="/Shota_Sometani" title="Shota Sometani">Shota Sometani</a> - Shinichi Izumi
</li><li> <a href="/Ai_Hashimoto" title="Ai Hashimoto">Ai Hashimoto</a> - Satomi Murano
</li><li> <a href="/Sadao_Abe" title="Sadao Abe">Sadao Abe</a> - Migi
</li><li> <a href="/Eri_Fukatsu" title="Eri Fukatsu">Eri Fukatsu</a> - Teacher Ryoko Tamiya
</li><li> <a href="/Masahiro_Higashide" title="Masahiro Higashide">Masahiro Higashide</a> - Hideo Shimada (mysterious transfer student)
</li><li> <a href="/Nao_Omori" title="Nao Omori">Nao Omori</a> - Kuramori (freelance journalist)
</li><li> <a href="/Pierre_Taki" title="Pierre Taki">Pierre Taki</a> - Miki
</li><li> <a href="/Hirofumi_Arai" title="Hirofumi Arai">Hirofumi Arai</a> - Uragami (serial killer)
</li><li> <a href="/Kazuki_Kitamura" title="Kazuki Kitamura">Kazuki Kitamura</a> - Takeshi Hirokawa (mysterious mayor candidate)
</li><li> <a href="/Tadanobu_Asano" title="Tadanobu Asano">Tadanobu Asano</a> - Goto (Takeshi Hirokawa’s bodyguard)
</li><li> <a href="/Kimiko_Yo" title="Kimiko Yo">Kimiko Yo</a> - Nobuko Izumi (Shinichi Izumi’s mother)
</li><li> <a href="/Jun_Kunimura" title="Jun Kunimura">Jun Kunimura</a> - Detective Hirama
</li><li> <a href="/Wataru_Ichinose_(1985)" title="Wataru Ichinose (1985)">Wataru Ichinose</a> - gang member
</li><li> <a href="/Roy_Kishima" title="Roy Kishima">Roy Kishima</a> - Roy Kishima
</li></ul>
```

alternatively, the html could also look like this:

```
<h2> <span class="mw-headline" id="Cast">Cast</span></h2>
<table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="0" style="text-align:center">
<tr>
<td width="100pt">
</td>
<td width="100pt">
</td>
<td width="100pt">
</td>
<td width="100pt">
</td>
<td width="100pt">
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td> <a href="/Ryosuke_Yamada" title="Ryosuke Yamada"><img alt="Assassination Classroom-Graduation-Ryosuke Yamada.jpg" src="/images/1/12/Assassination_Classroom-Graduation-Ryosuke_Yamada.jpg" width="90" height="83"/></a>
</td>
<td> <a href="/Masaki_Suda" title="Masaki Suda"><img alt="Assassination Classroom-Graduation-Masaki Suda.jpg" src="/images/4/45/Assassination_Classroom-Graduation-Masaki_Suda.jpg" width="90" height="90"/></a>
</td>
<td> <a href="/Maika_Yamamoto" title="Maika Yamamoto"><img alt="Assassination Classroom-Graduation-Maika Yamamoto.jpg" src="/images/e/e7/Assassination_Classroom-Graduation-Maika_Yamamoto.jpg" width="90" height="90"/></a>
</td>
<td> <a href="/Seika_Taketomi" title="Seika Taketomi"><img alt="Assassination Classroom-Graduation-Seika Taketomi.jpg" src="/images/c/ce/Assassination_Classroom-Graduation-Seika_Taketomi.jpg" width="90" height="90"/></a>
</td>
<td> <a href="/Mio_Yuki" title="Mio Yuki"><img alt="Assassination Classroom-Graduation-Mio Yuki.jpg" src="/images/b/b4/Assassination_Classroom-Graduation-Mio_Yuki.jpg" width="90" height="90"/></a>
</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

I DO NOT know the type of element that immediately follows h2 as a sibling node.
In most cases, the element that follows the `h2` element should be a table and this is what I want to check for. For this example, I need to detect that the element following h2 is not a table. To do so, I use

```
response.xpath('//h2/span[@id="Cast"]/../following-sibling::table')
```

to grab the following table. I would normally expect an empty list. However, this isn't working since there does happen to be a table, but it's many elements further down with completely unrelated content.

Is there a way to obtain information about the following-sibling that immediately follows a node?

Comment: In your example it is not a table but an unordered list. maybe thats why it is not working?

Comment: @nutmeg64, to clarify. For the above example, I need a way to detect that the element following h2 is not a table. The command that I used to obtain following-sibling::table would give me a list of table elements. I thought about checking to see if it was empty to determine that the element after h2 is not a table. However, with more tables afterwards, this wouldn't work.

Comment: Have you tried getting `h2`'s parent, from there get all of it's immediate children and get only the second one? (with indexing [2])

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the html that I am parsing has a really flat structure. That is, h2's parent is the body and it contains everything. This means that I don't know for sure that h2 is the first element in its parent. I suppose that I could get the parent and then search all of its children for h2 to find its index and then fetch the next sibling node? I wonder if there is a cleaner solution. @nutmeg64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get type (name) of the immediate following sibling node, you can try

```
//h2/following-sibling::*[1]/name()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wasn't aware of the fact that the wildcard could be used after following-sibiling.

Answer (score 1):

just to get the next sibling it would be something like:

```
(//h2/span[@id="Cast"]/../following-sibling::table)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, like in the example above, in the event that h2 is not followed by a table, I would potentially get a table that is not the immediate sibling of h2. What I need to be able to do is look at the following sibling of h2, regardless of its element type - ul or table, and determine its type. To put it another way, I don't know for sure, the type of the element that immediately follows h2 as a sibling node.